# How to open Excel's file in readonly mode?

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, browser

I am using VS2008, C#, with WPF application (WebBrowser and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel)
I have a task : Hosting Excel on WPF-form in mode readonly.

How can i do this:

First 1. Loading Excel file in WebBrowser

```
 Uri _uri = new Uri("FilePath");
 WebBrowserExcel.Navigate(_uri);
```

Next 2. In Event WebBrowserExcel_LoadCompleted

```
    if ((WebBrowserExcel.Document as Excel.Workbook) == null) return;
       try
       {
          //Get loading WorkBook and set "Protect" for disable editing 
          _Book = WebBrowserExcel.Document as Excel.Workbook;
          _Book.Protect("", Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

          //Set "Protect" for disable editing to WorkSheet
           foreach (Excel.Worksheet _sheet in _Book.Sheets)
           {
               _sheet.Protect(&quot;&quot;, Type.Missing,Type.Missing,
                              Type.Missing,Type.Missing, true,Type.Missing,
                              Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                              Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing,
                              Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing
                              );
            } 
        }
        .....
```

After this I have an Excel's MessageBox, when I try to edit file in WebBrowser. MessageBox's text:
"This Book is Protected...etc" or "This Sheet is Protected...etc"

To hide this messagebox i need to set the property
Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;

```
3. Set property

    _Book.Application.GetType().InvokeMember("DisplayAlerts", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, _Book.Application, new object[] { false });
```

and have Exception :

```
InnerException = {"could Not set the property DisplayAlerts Application class"}
```

but if create Application (not get from WebBrowserExcel.Document) I can set DisplayAlerts, but I can't hosting Excel.Application into WebBrowser, only Excel's file...

Are there ways to set Excel's file readonly inside WebBrowser? or how to set 'DisplayAlerts'?

Answer (score 0):

It's a Bag
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165435/en